# Perl rename command regex working weirdly with groups and hyphen

Tags: perl, regex, rename, batch-rename

I am trying to rename a bunch of file with `rename` perl utility

My replace string expression is `s/(\d)(?:-|_)*([A-Z]+)(?:-|_)*(\d+[A-Z]{0,2})(?:-|_)*([A-Z]{2})/$1-$2-$3-$4/`. I don't know much of perl so don't know if it is a easy thing.

When I try to use all 4 groups as back-reference using the `-`separator (`$1-$2-$3-$4`) I get the following:

```
rename -n 's/(\d)(?:-|_)*([A-Z]+)(?:-|_)*(\d+[A-Z]{0,2})(?:-|_)*([A-Z]{2})/$1-$2-$3-$4/' *

rename(1BI0001DES_agp.txt, 1-BI-0001D-ES_agp.txt)
rename(1CBN0001ES_agp.txt, 1-CBN-0001-ES_agp.txt)
rename(1CMO0002ES_agp.txt, 1-CMO-0002-ES_agp.txt)
rename(1FAL0002ES_agp.txt, 1-FAL-0002-ES_agp.txt)
rename(1FI0001ES_agp.txt, 1-FI-0001-ES_agp.txt)
rename(1LB0002ES_agp.txt, 1-LB-0002-ES_agp.txt)
rename(1LD0001ES_agp.txt, 1-LD-0001-ES_agp.txt)
rename(1LPB0001ES_agp.txt, 1-LPB-0001-ES_agp.txt)
rename(1NO0001ES_agp.txt, 1-NO-0001-ES_agp.txt)
rename(1NO0003ES_agp.txt, 1-NO-0003-ES_agp.txt)
rename(1RBN0003ES_agp.txt, 1-RBN-0003-ES_agp.txt)
rename(1SJ0001ES_agp.txt, 1-SJ-0001-ES_agp.txt)
rename(1SMO0003ES_agp.txt, 1-SMO-0003-ES_agp.txt)
rename(1SRN0001ES_agp.txt, 1-SRN-0001-ES_agp.txt)
rename(2NST0001ES_agp.txt, 2-NST-0001-ES_agp.txt)
```

whereas when I use the `_` (underline) or any other character separator (like `$1-$2-$3_$4`) I get a different result. This is the result I wanted but with hyphen. Any idea of what is going on?

```
rename -n 's/(\d)(?:-|_)*([A-Z]+)(?:-|_)*(\d+[A-Z]{0,2})(?:-|_)*([A-Z]{2})/$1-$2-$3_$4/' *

rename(1BI0001DES_agp.txt, 1-BI-0001D_ES_agp.txt)
rename(1-BRSA-241-ES_dados.txt, 1-BRSA-241_ES_dados.txt)
rename(1-BRSA-280-ES_dados.txt, 1-BRSA-280_ES_dados.txt)
rename(1-BRSA-478-ES_dados.txt, 1-BRSA-478_ES_dados.txt)
rename(1-BRSA-504D-ES_dados.txt, 1-BRSA-504D_ES_dados.txt)
rename(1-BRSA-512DA-ES_dados.txt, 1-BRSA-512DA_ES_dados.txt)
rename(1-BRSA-512DB-ES_dados.txt, 1-BRSA-512DB_ES_dados.txt)
rename(1-BRSA-512D-ES_dados.txt, 1-BRSA-512D_ES_dados.txt)
rename(1CBN0001ES_agp.txt, 1-CBN-0001_ES_agp.txt)
rename(1CMO0002ES_agp.txt, 1-CMO-0002_ES_agp.txt)
rename(1FAL0002ES_agp.txt, 1-FAL-0002_ES_agp.txt)
rename(1FI0001ES_agp.txt, 1-FI-0001_ES_agp.txt)
rename(1LB0002ES_agp.txt, 1-LB-0002_ES_agp.txt)
rename(1LD0001ES_agp.txt, 1-LD-0001_ES_agp.txt)
rename(1LPB0001ES_agp.txt, 1-LPB-0001_ES_agp.txt)
rename(1NO0001ES_agp.txt, 1-NO-0001_ES_agp.txt)
rename(1NO0003ES_agp.txt, 1-NO-0003_ES_agp.txt)
rename(1RBN0003ES_agp.txt, 1-RBN-0003_ES_agp.txt)
rename(1SJ0001ES_agp.txt, 1-SJ-0001_ES_agp.txt)
rename(1SMO0003ES_agp.txt, 1-SMO-0003_ES_agp.txt)
rename(1SRN0001ES_agp.txt, 1-SRN-0001_ES_agp.txt)
rename(2NST0001ES_agp.txt, 2-NST-0001_ES_agp.txt)
rename(4-BRSA-248-ES_dados.txt, 4-BRSA-248_ES_dados.txt)
rename(4-BRSA-253-ES_dados.txt, 4-BRSA-253_ES_dados.txt)
```

I just wanted my result with hyphens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this right, the offending files (`4-BRSA-248-ES_dados.txt`, for example), are already in the required format. Therefore no renaming is done and they're not in the output. From [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/prename.1.html):

```
"rename" renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified
as the first argument.  The perlexpr argument is a Perl expression
which is expected to modify the $_ string in Perl for at least some of
the filenames specified.  If a given filename is not modified by the
expression, it will not be renamed.  If no filenames are given on the
command line, filenames will be read via standard input.
```

For example, `touch foo; rename -n 's/foo/foo/' *` will output nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much it is exactly what happened. That file was already in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's the FIRST element in a `[]` match, `-` indicates a range. E.g. `[-AC]` matches `-`, `A` or `C`, while `[A-C]` matches `A,`B`or`C`.